# EntityFramework Code First with many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I try to create a code-first model based on an existing database with 3 tables:

```
Template
-------------
IdEnvironment
IdTemplate

Context
-------------
IdEnvironment
IdContext

ContextTemplate
-------------
IdEnvironment
IdTemplate
IdContext
```

I use the following code to build the model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
            .HasMany<Context>(e => e.Contexts)
            .WithMany(e => e.Templates)
            .Map(cs =>
                {
                    cs.MapLeftKey(new string[] { "IdEnvironment", "IdContext" });
                    cs.MapRightKey(new string[] { "IdEnvironment", "IdTemplate" });
                    cs.ToTable("ContextTemplate");
                });
```

When I try to create a migration, I get the following error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
IdEnvironment: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'IdEnvironment' is already defined.
TemplateContext: EntityType: EntitySet 'TemplateContext' is based on type 'TemplateContext' that has no keys defined.
```

Is there a way to fix the model without adding a `IdEnvironment2` column?

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of knowledge, but why didn't you just define model classes which match your expectations. Maybe your way is just the another way that I didn't know about.

Comment: I don't want the ContextTemplate table in my model since it is only a table that maps the relationships between Context and Template. It makes more sense to use context1.Templates than context1.ContextTemplates.Templates.